# SQL Server | Select all specific duplicate in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My problem right now is that I need to make an statement where select all rows that are duplicates with specific needs.

For example I got table 1 (users):

```
Users:
----------------------------------------------
ID  name   lastname   birth       file number
1   Max    Lix        2015-02-01  D43-892
2   Chris  Maura      2010-12-25  E33-722
4   Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S85-458
5   Max    Lix        2019-02-01  D23-992
6   Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S84-488
7   Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S75-258
----------------------------------------------

Address(u_ID = ID of Users table):
----------------------------------------------
ID   u_ID   Street   number   zip
1    1      Heystr.  12       4556
2    2      Nostr.   2        8978
3    4      Yesstr.  8a       2545
```

I need to get all rows where the name, lastname and birth does match with other rows and also get the address for that person.

The result should look like this:

```
 Result:
 ----------------------------------------------
 name   lastname   birth       filenumber   address
 Max    Lix        2015-02-01  D43-892      Heystr. 12 4556
 Max    Lix        2019-02-01  D23-992      Heystr. 12 4556
 Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S85-458      Yesstr. 8a 2545
 Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S84-488      Yesstr. 8a 2545
 Lena   Paul       2005-05-11  S75-258      Yesstr. 8a 2545
```

The first idea that I had was to use GROUP BY and HAVING but that does only return one row but I need every single duplicate matching the name, lastname and birth.

Comment: groupBy and having are correct, you can then using this query as subquery, or a self join to get all the values you need :)

Comment: Or EXISTS subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
select u.name, u.lastname, u.birth, u.filenumber, concat(a.street, ' ', a.number, ' ', a.zip) address
from users u
left join address a
on a.u_id = u.id
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from users 
    where users.name = u.name and user.lastname = u.lastname and user.birth = u.birth and users.id <> u.id
)
```

With the condition:

```
users.name = u.name and user.lastname = u.lastname and user.birth = u.birth and users.id <> u.id
```

you can find the dupilcates.
Use `inner join` instead of `left join` if you want the duplicates only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, lastname, birth, filenumber, concat(street,' ' , number, ' ', zip) as address
  FROM Users A, Adress
 WHERE u_id = a.id
   AND (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM Users B
         WHERE A.name = B.name
           AND A.lastname = B.lastname) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with duplicate as ( -- this CTE makes a list of duplicated user_IDs

   Select u.id
    from users 
    group by name, lastname, birth
    having count(*) >= 2
)

    Select concat(street,' ' , number, ' ', zip) as address, 
           name, lastname, birth, filenumber 
    from duplicates d -- gather the data
                      join addresses on d.id=uid 
                      join users on u.id=d.uid
```

will return you a report of all the people having an homonym with same birthday

Comment: fix the count to be > 1 or >= 2

Answer (score 0):

Please try below,

```
  select U.name,U.lastname,U.birth,U.filenumber,concat(street,' ',number,' ',zip) as address
    from Users U join Address A on 
    U.ID=A.u_Id
    group by name,lastname,birth
    having count(*)>1
```